# List of all valid categories for ImageIdentify?

Tags: image-processing, image, computer-vision

Can anyone give a list of valid categories for the second argument of ImageIdentify?

[image]

Comment: A valid category is any of the forms listed in the excerpt that you posted. There 117817 concept entities alone, so listing all possible category forms is not possible, but you can find them using `EntityList["Concept"]`. For the rest you should consult the respective documentation pages. The arbitrary entity form I believe you have to just try.

Comment: C.E. I tried a bunch of concepts that didn't work so I thought a definitive list would help

Comment: Then say that in the question, by now I think you've seen the question "what have you tried?" being asked here. It is always the case that people want to know. FWIW, I'm not sure your problem is answerable. I would probably run `ImageIdentify[img, All, 10]` and see what concepts it thinks the image is close to, and then use one of those concepts to make my request more specific. I assume that concept could then also be used for related images.

Comment: This is really not such a bad question. It might be useful to put the `EntityList["Concept"]` recommendation on the `ImageIdentify` page. A diagram that shows the relationships between `Entity...` functions and the terminology would be very useful.